# how to put loading icon before the page loads

Tags: php, jquery, linux, bootstrap-4

I have the following piece of code which is triggered by a button click.

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['click']))
            {
      echo "<div class='spinner-grow' role='status'>";
      echo "<span class='sr-only'>Loading...</span>";
      echo "</div>";

       shell_exec("perl myscript1.pl");
       shell_exec("perl myscript2.pl");

    echo "<div class='image'>";
    echo "<img src='figure.png' class='mx-auto d-block' style='width:800px; height:800px;'>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

the perl scripts inside that block will generate a image which i will load into page, but those two scripts take around 10s. So I am trying to put a boostrap spinner and have given a fadeout of 9.5s in jquery.

But the spinner and the image together load after 9.5s. The jquery code i am using is below. Kindly help what needs to be done.

```
$(function() {
  $(".spinner-grow").fadeOut(9500, function() {
    $(".image").fadeIn(500);
   });
});
```

Thanks,
Karthic

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a div just after  tag.

   `<div class="pre-loader"></div>`
      `

   `$(window).load(function() { 
      $(".pre-loader").fadeOut();
       //or your loading icon wrapped in the pre-loader class
       });`